# When can I cast Glyph of Destruction?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Glyph of Destruction](http://magiccards.info/lg/en/148.html) was originally worded: "Target wall you control gains +10/+0 when blocking." To me, that indicates that you could cast it any time, i.e. outside of combat.

However, the Gather wording is:

> Target blocking Wall you control gets +10/+0 until end of combat. Prevent all damage that would be dealt to it this turn. Destroy it at the beginning of the next end step.

Since Gatherer now says "Target blocking Wall", does that mean I have to declare the Wall as a blocker before I cast the Glyph? I'm trying to come up with some Glyph/Fling shenanigans for a deck and I need to know if I have to block before I use this trick.

Comment: The fact that the original fuzzy wording misled you is exactly why so many old cards have updated oracle text, with newer templating.

Comment: It's actually quite a large power difference between the two 'versions' of the cards. I know that Gatherer is supposed to clear up what the cards say, but it's quite a drop in power level.

Comment: You *might* have been able to cast it sooner before, but even then, the bonus only applied when blocking. I don't see this "drop in power level" you mention.

Comment: @Discord I'm not sure you actually could cast it outside of combat - that's what I was trying to say about original wording. It was *really fuzzy*. Things like this may well have been supposed to imply that you could only cast it while the Wall is blocking - look, it says "when blocking" on the card. If you try to read old cards as if they were written with the rules and templating clarity of more recent cards, you will be misled.

Comment: You guys are correct. They didn't nerf the power level at all, just clarified it. Now to select some ways to force my opponents to attack, so I can Glyph of Destruction to destroy their creature and then Fling my wall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your wall has to be declared a blocker before you can target it with that glyph. Your wall remains a blocker (and thus a legal target) until the end of that combat phase, though you'll have to target it before the Combat Damage step if you want it to actually deal that +10 damage in combat.

A creature is only considered blocking or attacking once it is declared as such, and ceases to be those things once combat is over. There is no such thing as a blocking or attacking creature outside of combat.

Comment: "before the combat damage step" -- No, the Glyph can be cast all the way up to the end of the End of Combat step (which comes after combat damage). Creatures continue to be attacking or blocking creatures until the start of the postcombat Main phase (or the start of the next Begin Combat  step, if you've achieved multiple Combat phases).

Comment: @BrianS That's true. I was only thinking about when you'd be able to target it to get it to deal damage, but it's certainly legal _after_ combat damage, and there are probably times when you'd want to target it afterwards.